# Salesforce org required with licenses same as developer edition but with higher space for file and data

Tags: developer-org

I need an org from salesforce with a space of minimum 1GB for file and at least 512mb for data storage. What edition should I opt for? Where can I connect with salesforce representatives with this requirement?

Comment: have you read through https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_storage_allocation.htm&type=0 ?

Comment: I have read this.. but when I try to raise a case with salesforce with developer edition login credentials , it doesn't allow me..! So let me know a possible mail ID to contact salesforce for org ..!

Comment: give them a call =P  https://www.salesforce.com/ca/form/contact/contactme.jsp

Comment: @glls .. Thankyou ..!

Comment: If you are an ISV Partner you could create a [Partner Developer Edition org](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Partner_Development_and_Test_Environments&oldid=126931) (Super-sized DE org). However, even that doesn't have a default 1GB of storage.

Comment: Can u get me the link to check how to become ISV partner..? It's a compromisable  storage demand @Daniel Ballinger

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks a lot. I was able to login to partner developer edition. It has 1 GB data storage and 12.5GB file storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments.

If you are an ISV Partner you can create a [Partner Developer edition org](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Partner_Development_and_Test_Environments&oldid=126931). This is sometimes refered to as a "Super-sized DE org". This will give you expanded data and file storage limits.

There are details about signing up to the ISV Partner program in [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/isv_developer_beginner/modules/isvforce_basics/units/isvforce_basics_partner_program).

With regards to the user expiration dates, it is likely tied to the type of org you created. For instance, the [Partner Test orgs](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Orgs) expire 1 year after creation.